# Simple print string array

Tags: arrays, string

Please let me know what is the mistake with this simple code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    int i,n;
    char a[100];
    clrscr();
    printf("\n Enter the size of the array");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\n Enter the array");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%s",a[i]);
    printf("\n Your array is \n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%s",a[i]);
    getch();
}
```

My input is 
Enter the size of the array
2
Enter the array
Apple
Banana
Your array
(null) (null)

Can someone explain why this is? Where am i going wrong?
Even if my input is single characters like a or s, this is the same output.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not declaring array of string itself.

By `char a[100];` means you are declaring an array which can hold 100 characters (one of them should be `NULL` for proper string termination). In other words you are declaring only one string.

Whereas you want an array of strings, thus you need to do something like `char a[10][100];`. This will declare an array of 10 strings, where every string can hold 100 characters.

After updating your code with `char a[10][100];`, I am getting following o/p (which you are looking for):

```
 Enter the size of the array3

 Enter the arrayhi
hello
com

 Your array is 
hi
hello
com
```

Comment: Yes. That's the one. Figured as soon as i posted this :P

Comment: @April you can upvote/accept answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here.

When calling scanf, you need to use the & operator and pass the address of the string, e.g.

```
scanf("%s", &a[i]);
```

Next is that a is an array of char, not an array of strings.  You might try

```
char a[20][100];
```

giving you 100 strings of 20 chars.

Answer (score 0):

I edit your code check:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int i,n;
    char a[100];
    printf("\n Enter the size of the array: \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){

        printf("\n Enter the array value:  \n");
        int input;
        scanf("%d",&input);
        a[i] = input;
    }

    printf("\n Your array is : ");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)

        printf("%d , ",a[i]);

    printf("\n");

}
```

your mistake was in the time to read the value and assign it to the array